# Adding capabilities to super admins

Tags: multisite, capabilities

I'm developing a plugin that uses custom capabilities. Some of those capabilities need to be added to all users who are super admins. Currently, I'm using this code:

```
$supers = get_super_admins();
foreach ( $supers as $admin ) {
    $user = new WP_User( 0, $admin );
    $user->add_cap( 'my_cap' );
    $user->add_cap( 'my_second_cap' );
}
```

However, I'm concerned that this code is just adding the capabilities to the individual users, as opposed to the role as I usually would. If a new super admin is created, they will not have these capabilities as this function only runs on plugin activation.

Is there a better way of adding custom capabilities to super admins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this isn't well documented, "Super Admin" is not a role (in that it is not an actual role object). It's more like a special "status".

A list of users who are Super Admins (also called "network admins" or "site admins") are stored in a database site-option record called `site_admins`. Generally, adding a capability to the Administrator role is enough since Super Admins are also, de facto, members of Administrator role with all it's capabilities.

That said, if you specifically need to add a capability only to Super Admins (but not "normal" administrators), it might be better to simply use WordPress's `is_super_admin()` function instead of using capabilities at all, since it is assumed that Super Admins have no restrictions.

If you really need to use capabilities, you should use the `grant_super_admin` and `remove_super_admin` hooks to add or remove capabilities to/from Super Admin users (respectively) *as soon as their Super Admin status changes*.

Now as far as changing capabilities for existing Super Admin users, your approach is the best … fetch a list of super admin users, loop through it, and add capabilities to each (although should only need to run that once *EVER* if you used the above hooks).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether it's single site or multisite.

**Multisite:**

Super admin has all capabilities unless specifically denied. From Core `class-wp-user.php::has_cap`:

```
if ( is_multisite() && is_super_admin( $this->ID ) ) {
    if ( in_array( 'do_not_allow', $caps ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Single site**

Super-admin cannot be added on Single Sites. From Core `capabilities.php::grant_super_admin()`:

```
function grant_super_admin( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $GLOBALS['super_admins'] ) || ! is_multisite() ) {
        return false;
    }
```

If for some reason a user has the super-admin status on a single site, it won't change anything in regards to what capability the user has.

Answer (score -1):

The things to do:

1. Get the author role.
2. Add capability to that role.

For example:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'author' );

    // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
    // would allow the author to edit others' posts for current theme only
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

> The code above is a snippet from [Function Reference/add_cap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but super admins is not a role per se, so I cannot use this method

Comment: Also, the Codex page you linked to recommends: This setting is saved to the database, so it might be better to run this on theme/plugin activation

Comment: I removed my recommendation from my answer, I didn't notice that part in the Codex page. But why wouldn't you make a role?

Comment: I do not want to create a custom role - I want to assign custom capabilities to all super admins. However, 'super admin' is *not* a role, and while the code I'm using *works*, I'm concerned if it's the best method.