# How to enable Admins to Install Plugins

Tags: plugins, multisite, admin, installation

I am running a multisite network on the latest version of WP. I am the Super Admin.

I setup a user as "Administrator" on a site in the network. The Admin User can see plugins but cannot install them (i.e., there is no Add New button on the plugin screen).

I am ever running WP User Role Editor plugin and the ability for an admin to install plugins is checked.

How can I give the secondary/alternate Admin the ability to install plugins?

Comment: This [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81907/adding-capabilities-to-super-admins) should to understand the Super Admin rights, there is not a role.

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).